# What brand of coroutine does Lua implement?

Tags: lua, coroutine

Can anyone tell me specifically what "flavor" of coroutine Lua implements? I ask because Lua's coroutines seem to be well suited to a problem of mine where I want to be able to pause a function at various points, possibly within nested function calls, and then resume it later. Despite having similar "coroutine/generator"-like constructs this doesn't seem to be possible in e.g. C# or JavaScript. What other languages support these types of coroutines?

Comment: Read the end of [this page](https://www.lua.org/pil/9.1.html)

Comment: TBH my takeaway from reading that is that no two coroutines are the same and neither is anyone's language for describing them...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The paper [Coroutines in Lua](http://dx.doi.org/10.3217/jucs-010-07-0910), which is freely available, says:

> Lua implements the concept of *asymmetric coroutines*, which are commonly denoted as *semi­symmetric* or *semi­coroutines* [Marlin, 1980], [Dahl et al., 1972]. Asymmetric coroutine facilities are so called because they involve two types of control transfer operations: one for (re)invoking a coroutine and one for suspending it, the latter returning control to the coroutine invoker. An asymmetric coroutine can be regarded as subordinate to its caller, the relationship between them being similar to that between a called and a calling routine. A different control discipline is implemented by *symmetric* coroutine facilities, which provide a single transfer operation for switching control to the indicated coroutine. Because symmetric coroutines are capable of passing control between themselves, they are said to operate at the same hierarchical level. The following arguments justify why Lua offers asymmetric coroutines, instead of providing symmetric facilities or both mechanisms.